# I have mounted My .obb file, but how to get the final path to my assets

Tags: android, apk-expansion-files

i have mounted an obb file and i got a path like this `/mnt/obb/880f5ef6a6885d1b8937f9625be73850` , 
but how to get the final path to my assets ( myAssets folder in the .obb file)?

Also when i browse to this directory i find it **empty** !

I have used this method to mount my .obb file

```
 public void mountExpansion() {
        final StorageManager storageManager  = (StorageManager) getSystemService(STORAGE_SERVICE);



        String packageName = "com.example.android";
        String filePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                + "/Android/obb/" + packageName + "/" + "main."
                + xAPKS[0].mFileVersion + "." + packageName + ".obb";
        final File mainFile = new File(filePath);
        if (mainFile.exists()) {
            Log.d(TAG, "FILE: " + filePath + " Exists");
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "FILE: " + filePath + " DOESNT EXIST");
        }


        if (!storageManager.isObbMounted(mainFile.getAbsolutePath())) {
            if (mainFile.exists()) {
                if(storageManager.mountObb(mainFile.getAbsolutePath(), null,
                        new OnObbStateChangeListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onObbStateChange(String path, int state) {
                                super.onObbStateChange(path, state);
                                Log.d("PATH = ",path);
                                Log.d("STATE = ", state+"");
                                expansionFilePath =   storageManager.getMountedObbPath(path);
                                if (state == OnObbStateChangeListener.MOUNTED) {
                                    expansionFilePath = storageManager
                                            .getMountedObbPath(path);
                                    Log.d(TAG,expansionFilePath+"-->MOUNTED");

                                } 
                                else {
                                    Log.d(TAG, "Path: " + path + "; state: " + state);
                                }
                            }
                        }))
                {
                    Log.d(TAG,"SUCCESSFULLY QUEUED");
                }
                else
                {
                    Log.d(TAG,"FAILED");
                }

            } else {
                Log.d(TAG, "Patch file not found");
            }
        }else {

        }





    }
```

I have this message on the log

```
FILE: /storage/sdcard0/Android/obb/com.example.android/main.1014001.com.example.android.obb Exists
SUCCESSFULLY QUEUED
/mnt/obb/880f5ef6a6885d1b8937f9625be73850-->MOUNTED
```

Thanks.

Comment: If the directory is empty then it makes not much sence looking for a path to an assets folder. Unless you want to put something in it in which case you could first create it. But i understand that you expect such a folder already there? I conclude that your obb file is empty then. But i have never done such thing...

Comment: but i can't load assets from this path, for example  :/mnt/obb/880f5ef6a6885d1b8937f9625be73850/image.png or /mnt/obb/880f5ef6a6885d1b8937f9625be73850/myassets/image.png doesn't exist

Comment: You already said that the directory was empty. So why are you trying to load?

Comment: Because in my expansion file ( main.1014001.com.example.android.obb) i have about 50Mb of assets

Comment: So you have to find out why you don't 'see' anything in that directory. When i use a file explorer then the directory is readable. So if there was something you would see it. `and i got a path like this` How did you get the path? There are app specific obb directories in (something like) /storage/sdcard0/Android/obb

Comment: I pushed my obb file in /storage/sdcard0/Android/obb and after this i have mounted it using `mount Expansion()` method, and i print  the path of the mounted file

Comment: And what is now in /storage/sdcard0/Android/obb  ?

Comment: There is com.example.android/main.1014001.com.example.android.obb

Comment: Is it normal that  com.example.android is twice in that path?

Comment: Yes, it's pakageName/obbFileName

Answer (score -1):

```
obbPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + File.separator + "Android/obb/" + getPackageName() + File.separator + "main.3." + getPackageName() + ".obb";
storageManager = (StorageManager)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.STORAGE_SERVICE);
m_filePathString = storageManager.getMountedObbPath(obbPath) + File.separator + filename;
```